# Magento2 Extension-Attribute of type \DateTime?

Tags: magento2, extension-attributes

I'am trying to add an extension-attribute to Magento_Customer like this:

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
    <attribute code="some_attribute" type="\DateTime" />
</extension_attributes>
```

The goal is to have a datetime-Column in SQL and an \DateTime-Object in PHP.

But every time I try to do this it somehow ends in an reflection error like this:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Each getter must have a doc block. See DateTime::format()
```

I've tried to wrap this in an extra getter/setter-Class and not to use \DateTime directly as an extension attribute but at some point is has to return \DateTime from a getter and this will also be picked up recursively by the reflections implementation of Magento2.

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't defined extension attribute's type as DateTime so you have to defined it as string type so your code will look like.

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface">
   <attribute code="some_attribute" type="string" />
</extension_attributes>
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: thx thats all i neede confirmed - string would work - but i added a custom interface with non getter that returns datetime - not standard but it works